# Screensaver greyed out in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

Recently upgraded to Mountain Lion, noticed my screensaver has stopped coming on (on mains, my laptop will quite happily sit awake and idling for 4+ hours.

My power saver settings are on 15 minutes to sleep, sharing is disabled on everything, and for some reason my screensaver time has been greyed out - I hadn't noticed that before and was wondering if it had any fundamental causes?

The laptop is a Late 2011 MBP 13, connected to a NAS drive (but not actively, same happens when disconnected). Connected to an external display, no apps in the background.

Comment: In addition to no screensaver, it also doesn't sleep?

Comment: Indeed. It'll just sit idling for hours - I left it doing some FTP operations last night, in the hope that it would sleep on completion - it didn't.

Comment: @iampearce what is your screensaver currently set to? is it a built in or third party screen saver?

Comment: Built in, tiled images coming from a folder. I don't have caffeine or anything else like that enabled which would block it, either.

Comment: Since it doesn't even sleep after 15 minutes of no activity, maybe there is always activity ... something is going on all the time.

Comment: But the screensaver time option is greyed out. Something is clearly blocking it?